# Open sets in a discrete product space.

Tags: general-topology, product-space

How is it possible for a countably infinite product space to be discrete?

If we let each $(X_i,T_i)$ be topological spaces with more than $1$ point and $$\prod^{\infty}_{i=1}(X_i,T_i)$$ be the countably infinite product space, then $$\prod^{\infty}_{i=1}\{a_i\} \subseteq \prod^{\infty}_{i=1}(X_i,T_i)$$ and is therefore an open set in the product space.  But in a product space, open sets are of the form $U = \{\prod ^{\infty}_{i=1}O_i : O_i \in T_i$ and $O_i = X_i$ for all but a finite number of $i \}$.

This seems to be a contradiction.  Can someone explain to me what I'm not understanding?

Comment: What makes you think the product of all these singletons, which is itself a singleton, is necessarily open?

Comment: The product (with the usual product topology) of infinitely many spaces, each having at least two points, is not discrete.  Your question essentially contains the proof of this fact.

Comment: @IttayWeiss  Because a space is discrete, then every subset is an open set.  Therefore since $\prod^{\infty}_{i=1}\{a_i\}$ is a subset of the discrete space $\prod^{\infty}_{i=1}(X_i,T_i)$ that implies that $\prod^{\infty}_{i=1}\{a_i\}$ is an open subset of $\prod^{\infty}_{i=1}(X_i,T_i)$.

Comment: It depends on the topology you give on the product space. If you use the product topology, then this space is not discrete. But if you use box topology, then it can be discrete.

Comment: So would it make sense to say that the product space is discrete iff every $(X_i,T_i)$ is discrate and all but a finite amount of the $(X_i,T_i)$ spaces are singleton sets because of the requirements of an open set for the product topology?

Comment: Yes. Unless specified, the product topology is the default one on a product space.

Comment: Something else to pointed out.  The set $U$ that you give does not consist of all open sets in the product topology. It is only a basis for that topology.